# Differentiable but not Holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can I get a few examples of complex functions being complex differentiable at a point but not holomorphic in their domain?

Comment: Do you mean real differentiable, or even $C^{\infty}$, but not holomorphic? I think you need to specify what you mean.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  Differentiable in the complex sense at some point?

Comment: I assume you mean differentiable interpreted as a function $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$. Take any polynomial in ${\rm Re}(z)$ and ${\rm Im}(z)$ that is not a polynomial in $z$. For example, ${\rm Re}(z)$ and ${\rm Im}(z)$ themselves. If you mean complex-differentiable in a nbhd of a point but not holomorphic at the point, then you'll run into a problem: there aren't any. Not sure what can be said pointwise.

Answer (score 6):

$$
f(z) = |z|^2
$$
This is differentiable at just one point, $z=0$.  If "holomorophic at $0$" were construed as meaning differentiable everywhere in some open neighborhood of $0$, then this would not be holomorphic at $0$.  But I'm not sure that conventional definitions are sufficiently standard that you can say "holomorphic but not differentiable" and have everybody understand it in the same way.